# Using INDEX MATCH in VBA with Variable Lookup Locations

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble using variables within the lookup criteria in Index Match. Some background: I use the following code to set a variable's value to the row # of whatever cell contains "Current" within column B:

```
Dim rowHeaderNum As Integer

    rowHeaderNum = 0

    On Error Resume Next
    rowHeaderNum = Application.Match("Current", ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Then I use the below to store the column # of the cell within the row 'rowHeaderNum' that contains the value "CurrentActual" to another variable:

```
Dim currActColNum As Integer

currActColNum = 0
    currActColNum = Application.Match("CurrentActual", Rows(rowHeaderNum & ":" & rowHeaderNum), 0)
```

Below is the Index Match line that I can't get to work:

```
Dim currActRev As Double

    currActRev = Application.Index(Columns(currActColNum), Application.Match("Gross Operating Profit", Columns("N:N"), 0))
```

`currActRev` will store a dollar amount. The `Match` function will always use column N as the lookup array. When I run the `Index` `Match` line I get a

> type mismatch

error in the debugger.

Comment: Does Application even have a Index or Match method?

Comment: @siggi_pop yes, they exist.

Comment: Like someone else answered you should probably use the correct methods that WorksheetFunction provides `WorksheetFunction.Match` and  `WorksheetFunction.Index`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I use `WorksheetFunction` since in my version of Excel i cant's access `Application.Index`

Comment: @siggi_pop Both `Application.Match` and `WorksheetFunction.Match` are correct and both exist in your Excel (the first one just doesn't have intelli sense tool tips). They only differ in how they handle errors. While `WorksheetFunction` throws an exception that can be catched with `On Error …` the `Application` functions do not thorw an exeption but return an error code as result. See my edited answer below for an example how they both can be used.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `WorksheetFunction …`

`Application.Match` and `On Error Resume Next` does not work, because `Application.Match` does not throw exceptions you need to use `WorksheetFunction.Match` instead.

According to the documentation the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) it returns a `Double` so you need to `Dim RowHeaderNum As Double`.

```
Dim RowHeaderNum As Double
'RowHeaderNum = 0 'not needed it is always 0 after dim

On Error Resume Next
RowHeaderNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Current", ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), False)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Furthermore you need to check if `RowHeaderNum` is `0` and stop proceeding otherwise the following code will fail because row `0` does not exist.

```
If RowHeaderNum = 0 Then
    MsgBox "'Current' not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You need to do exactly the same here

```
Dim CurrActColNum As Double
On Error Resume Next
CurrActColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CurrentActual", Rows(RowHeaderNum), False)
On Error GoTo 0

If CurrActColNum = 0 Then
    MsgBox "'CurrentActual' not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Finally the [WorksheetFunction.Index method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.index) returns a `Variant` not a `Double` and you need error handling here too.

```
Dim currActRev As Variant
On Error Resume Next
currActRev = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Columns(CurrActColNum), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Gross Operating Profit", Columns("N:N"), False))
On Error GoTo 0

Debug.Print currActRev 'print result in immediate window
```

---

#### Using `Application …`

Note that you can also use the `Application.Match` and `Application.Index` (without `WorksheetFunction`) but then you cannot use `On Error …` and you have to check for errors using `IsError()`. Also your variables need to be declared as `Variant` then because `Application.Match` can either return a typo `Double` or a type `Error`.

```
Dim RowHeaderNum As Variant
RowHeaderNum = Application.Match("Current", ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), False)

If IsError(RowHeaderNum) Then
    MsgBox "'Current' not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim CurrActColNum As Variant
CurrActColNum = Application.Match("CurrentActual", Rows(RowHeaderNum), False)

If IsError(CurrActColNum) Then
    MsgBox "'CurrentActual' not found."
    Exit Sub
End If


Dim currActRev As Variant, currMatch As Variant
currMatch = Application.Match("Gross Operating Profit", Columns("N:N"), False)
If Not IsError(currMatch) Then
    currActRev = Application.Index(Columns(CurrActColNum), currMatch)
End If

Debug.Print currActRev 'print result in immediate window
```